# Select de duas colunas exibindo também o que não se relaciona

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Olá, estou tendo a seguinte dificuldade: Estou usando um Select que engloba duas tabelas **tb_doenca** e **tb_vacina**, porém ele não exibe todos os valores.

---

**EXEMPLO**
[image: tb_doenca]

Na tabela **tb_doenca** existem 33 registros, porém quando uso a seguinte querry: `select tb_doenca.nome_doenca,  count(tb_vacina.nome_vacina) AS qt from tb_doenca join tb_vacina on nome_doenca = comb_vacina GROUP BY comb_vacina ORDER BY count(tb_vacina.nome_vacina)` ele retorna apenas 30 registros, provavelmente por que não há relacionamento entre a **tb_doenca** e a **tb_vacina** nos registros... Queria saber uma maneira de mostrar todas as doenças e nos registros que não houverem nenhuma vacina para uma doença ela seja mesmo assim exibida com 0

---

**tb_vacina**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Comando**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: amigo usa left join, acho q resolve o seu problema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utilize `LEFT JOIN`, assim todos os registros da tabela principal `tb_doenca` serão retornados, juntamente com aqueles que coincidirem com eles na tabela auxiliar `tb_vacina` através do teste `nome_doenca = comb_vacina`:

```
select 
  tb_doenca.nome_doenca,
  count(tb_vacina.nome_vacina) AS qt 
from 
  tb_doenca left join tb_vacina on nome_doenca = comb_vacina 
GROUP BY comb_vacina 
ORDER BY count(tb_vacina.nome_vacina);
```

Demonstração no SQL Fiddle utilizando doenças fictícias extraídas do jogo [Theme Hospital](https://strategywiki.org/wiki/Theme_Hospital/Diseases) =D: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0f374e/2

Para entender melhor o uso dos diversos tipos de `JOIN`, eu sempre recomendo este site: http://www.sql-join.com/sql-join-types/

---

Em tempo, sugiro evitar estabelecer relacionamentos entre tabelas utilizando campos de texto que (aparentemente) serão inseridos via digitação, como `comb_vacina`. Um *input* errado acabaria por duplicar registros em consultas agregadoras como essa. Experimente criar uma tabela de relacionamentos com duas colunas, uma com o `id` da doença e outra com o `id` da vacina correspondente. Assim você tem um registro "estanque" para cada par "doença <-> vacina".